# Why is EasyAdmin 4 function configureMenuItems() in DashboardController not working?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, symfony6

I am currently using EasyAdmin 4 with Symfony to create a backend admin page to manage users.
I did all the step that was in the documentation but yet it still giving me an error:
**"Unable to find the controller related to the "App\Controller\Admin\User" Entity; did you forget to extend "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController"?"**

Here is the code in DashboardController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
       
        return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig');
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Symfony Melody')
            ->renderContentMaximized();
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home');
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('User', 'fas fa-user', User::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the code in UserCrudController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\User;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return User::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud;
    }

    /*
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id'),
            TextField::new('title'),
            TextEditorField::new('description'),
        ];
    }
    */
}
```

Here is the code in the User class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account with this email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $nom = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $prenom = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I tried reading the documentation again but i can't find any answers.
Can someone help please? it would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are Missing the use of `App\Entity\User`
In your DashboardController try to add this line :

```
use App\Entity\User;
```

On the top of your class file

Happy coding